# How to get the type for a List<aType>?

Tags: java

I have defined an object which takes a type parameter in its constructor :

```
public DynParameterDaoImpl(Class<T1> type) {
        super();
        ...
    }
```

The instanciation works well doing

```
DynParameterDaoImpl myVar = new DynParameterDaoImpl(Atype.class);
```

Is there a way to do this with type being a list. The following does not work..

```
DynParameterDaoImpl myVar = new DynParameterDaoImpl(List<Atype>.class);
```

Comment: Look into type tokens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

`List<AType>` is a type but it is not a class because type erasure ensures that `List<X>` is represented by the same class as `List<Y>` for all reference types `X` and `Y`.

For example,

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();  // Legal
boolean b = strings instanceof List<Number>;  // Compiler Rejects
```

The compiler rejects the `instanceof` check because there isn't enough information available to the virtual machine to distinguish between `List<String>` and `List<Number>`.

If it were possible to get a class value for a non-class type like `List<String>`, then the reflective equivalent

```
Class<? extends List<String>> stringListClass = strings.getClass();  // Illegal
Class<? extends List<Number>> numberListClass = List<Number>.class;  // Illegal
boolean b = numberListClass.isAssignableFrom(stringListClass);
```

would pass which would be a silent violation of type-safety.

Comment: Thanks for the very clear informations. I have achieved what I wanted to do by encapsulating the `List <Atype>` into a `class ATypeList` with getters and setters on `List <Atype>` and everything works well now.

Answer (score 2):

Let me quote *Effective Java*.

> There are two minor exceptions to the rule that you should not use raw types in new code, both of which stem from the fact that generic type information is erased at runtime. You must use raw types in class literals. The specification does not permit the use of parameterized types (though it does permit array types and primitive types) In other words, `List.class`, `String[].class`, and `int.class` are all legal, but `List<String>.class` and `List<?>.class` are not.